# R: Looping over custom dplyr function

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, purrr, nse

I want to build a custom dplyr function and iterate over it ideally with purrr::map to stay in the tidyverse.

To keep things as easy as possible I replicate my problem using a very simple summarize function.

When buildings custom functions with dplyr I ran into the problem of non-standard evaluation (NSE). I found three different ways to deal with it. Each way of dealing with NSE works fine when the function is called directly, but not when looping over it. Below you’ll find the code to replicate my problem. What would be the correct way to make my function work with purrr::map?

```
    # loading libraries
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(purrr)

    # generate test data
    test_tbl <- rbind(tibble(group = rep(sample(letters[1:4], 150, TRUE), each = 4),
                             score = sample(0:10, size = 600, replace = TRUE)),

                      tibble(group = rep(sample(letters[5:7], 50, TRUE), each = 3),
                             score = sample(0:10, size = 150, replace = TRUE))
    )




    # generate two variables to loop over
    test_tbl$group2 <- test_tbl$group
    vars <- c("group", "group2")


    # summarise function 1 using enquo()
    sum_tbl1 <- function(df, x) {

        x <- dplyr::enquo(x)

        df %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!! x) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                             n = dplyr::n())

    }

    # summarise function 2 using .dots = lazyeval
    sum_tbl2 <- function(df, x) {

        df %>%
            dplyr::group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(x)) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                             n = dplyr::n())

    }

    # summarise function 3 using ensym()
    sum_tbl3 <- function(df, x) {

        df %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::ensym(x)) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                             n = dplyr::n())

    }


    # Looping over the functions with map
    # each variation produces an error no matter which function I choose

    # call within anonymous function without pipe
    map(vars, function(x) sum_tbl1(test_tbl, x))
    map(vars, function(x) sum_tbl2(test_tbl, x))
    map(vars, function(x) sum_tbl3(test_tbl, x))

    # call within anonymous function witin pipe
    map(vars, function(x) test_tbl %>% sum_tbl1(x))
    map(vars, function(x) test_tbl %>% sum_tbl2(x))
    map(vars, function(x) test_tbl %>% sum_tbl3(x))

    # call with formular notation without pipe
    map(vars, ~sum_tbl1(test_tbl, .x))
    map(vars, ~sum_tbl2(test_tbl, .x))
    map(vars, ~sum_tbl3(test_tbl, .x))

    # call with formular notation within pipe
    map(vars,  ~test_tbl %>% sum_tbl1(.x))
    map(vars,  ~test_tbl %>% sum_tbl2(.x))
    map(vars,  ~test_tbl %>% sum_tbl3(.x))
```

I know that there are other solutions for producing summarize tables in a loop, like calling map directly and creating an anonymous function inside map (see code below). However, the problem I am interested in is how to deal with NSE in loops in general.

```
# One possibility to create summarize tables in loops with map
 vars %>%
    map(function(x){
        test_tbl %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::ensym(x)) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                             n = dplyr::n())
    })
```

### Update:

Below akrun provides a solution that makes the call via purrr::map() possible. A direct call to the function is then however only possible by calling the grouping variable as a string either directly

```
sum_tbl(test_tbl, “group”)
```

or indirectly as

```
sum_tbl(test_tbl, vars[1])
```

In this solution it is not possible to call the grouping variable in a normal dplyr way as

```
sum_tbl(test_tbl, group)
```

Eventually, it seems to me that solutions to NSE in custom dpylr functions can address the problem either at the level of the function call itself, then using map/lapply is not possible, or NSE can be adressed to work with iterations, then variables can only be called as "strings".

Building on akruns answer I built a workaround function which allows both strings and normal variable names in the function call. However, there are definitely better ways to make this possible. Ideally, there is a more straight-forward way of dealing with NSE in custom dplyr functions, so that a workaround, like the one below, is not necessary in the first place.

```
sum_tbl <- function(df, x) {

        x_var <- dplyr::enquo(x)

        x_env <- rlang::get_env(x_var)

        if(identical(x_env,empty_env())) {

            # works, when x is a string and in loops via map/lapply
            sum_tbl <- df %>%
                dplyr::group_by(!! rlang::sym(x)) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE),
                                 n = dplyr::n())

        } else {
            # works, when x is a normal variable name without quotation marks
            x = dplyr::enquo(x)

            sum_tbl <- df %>%
                dplyr::group_by(!! x) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE),
                                 n = dplyr::n())
        }

        return(sum_tbl)
    }
```

### Final update/solution

In an updated version of his answer akrun provides a solution which accounts for four ways of calling variable x:

1. as a normal (non-string) variable name: `sum_tbl(test_tbl, group)`
2. as a string name: `sum_tbl(test_tbl, "group")`
3. as an indexed vector: `sum_tbl(test_tbl, !!vars[1])`
4. and as a vector within `purr::map()`: `map(vars, ~ sum_tbl(test_tbl,
   !!.x))`

In (3) and (4) it is necessary to unquote the variable x using `!!`.

If I would use the function for myself only, this wouldn’t be a problem, but as soon as other team members use the function I would need to explain, document the function.

To avoid this, I now extended akrun’s solution to account for all four ways without unquoting. However, I am not sure whether this solution created other pitfalls.

```
sum_tbl <- function(df, x) {

    # if x is a symbol such as group without strings, than turn it into a string    
    if(is.symbol(get_expr(enquo(x))))  {

        x <- quo_name(enquo(x))

    # if x is a language object such as vars[1], evaluate it
    # (this turns it into a symbol), then turn it into a string
    } else if (is.language(get_expr(enquo(x))))  {

        x <- eval(x)
        x <- quo_name(enquo(x))

    } 

      # this part of the function works with normal strings as x
        sum_tbl <- df %>%
            dplyr::group_by(!! rlang::sym(x)) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE),
                             n = dplyr::n())

    return(sum_tbl)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `group_by_at` that can take a string as argument

```
sum_tbl1 <- function(df, x) {



            df %>%
                dplyr::group_by_at(x) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                                 n = dplyr::n())

        }
```

and then call as

```
out1 <- map(vars, ~ sum_tbl1(test_tbl, .x))
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `sym`bol and then evaluate (`!!`) within `group_by`

```
sum_tbl2 <- function(df, x) {



            df %>%
                dplyr::group_by(!! rlang::sym(x)) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                                 n = dplyr::n())

        }

out2 <- map(vars, ~ sum_tbl2(test_tbl, .x))

identical(out1 , out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If we specify one of the parameters, we don't have to provide the second argument, thus can also run without anonymous call

```
map(vars, sum_tbl2, df = test_tbl)
```

### Update

If we wanted to use it with conditions mentioned in the updated OP's post

```
sum_tbl3 <- function(df, x) {

           x1 <- enquo(x)
           x2 <- quo_name(x1)

            df %>%
                dplyr::group_by_at(x2) %>%
                dplyr::summarise(score = mean(score, na.rm =TRUE),
                                 n = dplyr::n())

        }


sum_tbl3(test_tbl, group)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  group score     n
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a      5.43   148
#2 b      5.01   144
#3 c      5.35   156
#4 d      5.19   152
#5 e      5.65    72
#6 f      5.31    36
#7 g      5.24    42

sum_tbl3(test_tbl, "group")
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  group score     n
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a      5.43   148
#2 b      5.01   144
#3 c      5.35   156
#4 d      5.19   152
#5 e      5.65    72
#6 f      5.31    36
#7 g      5.24    42
```

or call from 'vars'

```
sum_tbl3(test_tbl, !!vars[1])
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  group score     n
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a      5.43   148
#2 b      5.01   144
#3 c      5.35   156
#4 d      5.19   152
#5 e      5.65    72
#6 f      5.31    36
#7 g      5.24    42
```

and with `map`

```
map(vars, ~ sum_tbl3(test_tbl, !!.x))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  group score     n
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a      5.43   148
#2 b      5.01   144
#3 c      5.35   156
#4 d      5.19   152
#5 e      5.65    72
#6 f      5.31    36
#7 g      5.24    42

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  group2 score     n
#  <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#1 a       5.43   148
#2 b       5.01   144
#3 c       5.35   156
#4 d       5.19   152
#5 e       5.65    72
#6 f       5.31    36
#7 g       5.24    42
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This solution is on point. I just wonder why there is such a big fuzz about NSE and dplyr and all the workarounds I found on the web, including the tidyverse vignette on programming with dplyr(https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) when there is such a simple solution as group_by_at.

Comment: @Hellwalker  With `tidyverse`, multiple functions are being constructed daily.  So, when the article was created, probably there may be only a few ways to deal with it

Comment: After playing around with your solution I realized, that it helps to make the call via map() possible, but now calling the function directly yields an error. An ideal solution would work both ways, directly and via map/lapply. At the moment it looks like the problem of NSE can only be solved on one level: either when calling a function directly or when creating a function which then can only be used in iterations.

Comment: @Hellwalker Sorry, I didn't understand how you are calling.  `sum_tbl1(test_tbl, vars[1])` is working fine for me or `sum_tbl1(test_tbl1, "group")`  If you are interested in unquoting, then the `enquo` in your function comes into play

Comment: that's true. sum_tbl1(test_tbl, vars[1]) is working, but sum_tbl1(test_tbl, group) is not. I elaborated a little bit more on the problem in an updated version of my question.

Comment: @Hellwalker  For that you need to `enquo(group)` and then within `group_by(!! enquo(group))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190255/discussion-between-hellwalker-and-akrun).

Comment: Building on your updated answer I came up with an approach where unquoting is not needed in the function call. Thanks again!